# ASP.NET MVC Web API System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a front-end mvc application that is trying to call the API endpoint `http://ordersuat/session/login`

The code is as follows:

```
BearerToken token = new BearerToken();
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var tokenRequest = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", model.Email),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", model.Password)
    };
    var url = $"{Request.Url.Scheme}://{Request.Url.Authority}/session/login";
    HttpContent encodedRequest = new FormUrlEncodedContent(tokenRequest);
    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, encodedRequest).Result;
}
```

I have recently deployed the application to a web server running IIS but upon reaching `httpClient.PostAsync()` it throws `System.Net.WebException: The remote name cannot be resolved: 'ordersuat'`

I'm not sure if it's a problem with the IIS configuration as running it locally doesn't result in the exception.

From my client machine I can successfully ping **ordersuat/**, but trying to ping it while on remote desktop to the server results in `Ping request could not find host ordersuat`

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Update:** I added a default proxy into the web.config and things seem to be working now.

```
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="false">
    <proxy proxyAddress="http://[server-ip]:[port-number]/"
</defaultProxy>
```

Not 100% sure this is the optimal solution though, so I'm still open to any advice!